# Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Tags: xml, spring, spring-security

I am getting this exception when migrating Spring security version 3 to 4. I am implementing it using Sprig 4 XML based security. Your will be really appreciated

**Exception**:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'util:list#f1d6071': Cannot create inner bean 'security:filter-chain#1c5c0deb' of 
>   type [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain] while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [10]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Bea
>   nCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'security:filter-chain#1c5c0deb': C**annot resolve reference to bean 'adminConsoleDeniedExceptionTranslationFilter' while setting co
>   nstructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adminConsoleDeniedExceptionTranslationF
>   ilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to a
>   void type ambiguities**)

at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEAS
E]

spring-security.xml (A small portion of impacted Spring 4 XML config)

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
  <constructor-arg>
      <util:list>
          <security:filter-chain pattern="/refreshCache**" filters="scpf,noFilter,logoutFilter"/>
          <security:filter-chain pattern="/admin/adminConsole/**" filters="scpf,dsToSpringFilter,securityFilter,logoutFilter,
            fsi,adminConsoleDeniedExceptionTranslationFilter,adminConsoleFilter"/>
      </util:list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean><bean id="etf"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"/>
</bean><bean id="adminConsoleDeniedExceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
       <constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint2" ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"/>
       <constructor-arg ref="adminConsoleAccessDeniedHandler"/></bean><bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/><bean id="adminConsoleAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl"><property name="errorPage" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/adminConsoleAccessDenied.jsp"/></bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name attribute in first constructor-arg (of bean `adminConsoleDeniedExceptionTranslationFilter`) has weird value `authenticationEntryPoint2`:

```
<bean id="adminConsoleDeniedExceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationEntryPoint2" ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="adminConsoleAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</bean>
```

It should be `authenticationEntryPoint` according [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.html#ExceptionTranslationFilter%28org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint,%20org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache%29).

And else, second constructor-arg has no `name` attribute. Consider either to add `name` attribute, or remove both.